# mysql csv file import issue

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL on Mac OSX. When executing the following statement (from MySQl workbench), I met with the following error,

I tried to start MySQL manually using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` without any options, but still have this error. Wondering if any solutions?

I searched some solutions and looks like on Windows there are some .ini config files, but have not found any solutions on Mac OSX. Thanks.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/foo/Downloads/import.csv' 
INTO TABLE tasks 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement    0.0043 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to put the file into the server's data directory before trying to load it, for security reasons. Read more about [LOAD DATA in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), especially about the input file location. Note also: the secure-file-priv option can be set in a config file, hence manually starting the server without any additional option will not change its behavior compared to the normal start.

Comment: Thanks Mike, vote up for your reply. Wondering how to find the data directory on Mac OSX? I read your referred document and seems no answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Mike, mark your reply as answer.